# Using powershell to pull active users email address that belong to a certain group and are active

Tags: powershell, active-directory, ldap-query

I am trying to use Powershell to pull All members of a Active Directory group who are currently active (both account is enabled and not expired).

I thought what I had worked but I noticed that some users that have expiration dates in the future were ignored.  I tried added () around the AccountExpirationDate check because if they don't have a expiration date or if that date is in the future they are currently active.  When I use the () I get no results.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

```
Get-ADGroupMember 'Employees' |
  Get-ADUser -Properties Enabled, EmailAddress,AccountExpirationDate |
  Where-Object {$_.mail -like '@domain.com' -and $_.AccountExpirationDate -gt (Get-Date) -or $_.AccountExpirationDate -eq $null -and $_.Enabled -eq $True } |
  Select-Object  GivenName,Surname, EmailAddress,AccountExpirationDate| 
#Select-Object  -expand EmailAddress
Export-csv -path "export.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

User must be a member of x group.
Users account must be active
users account cannot be expired
List their First Name, Last Name and Email address

Comment: Use the `-LDAPFilter`, those queries are much more reliable. This should do it for active users only: `(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user)(!userAccountControl:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=2)(mail=*@domain.com) )`.   Check this site for info on the userAccountControl: http://www.selfadsi.org/ads-attributes/user-userAccountControl.htm

Comment: You might also want to try: `!userAccountControl:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=514`. Using the `514` should make the objectClass and category check unnecessary further increasing performance when dealing with a large set of objects

Answer (score 0):

[Max](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75011044/using-powershell-to-pull-active-users-email-address-that-belong-to-a-certain-gro#comment132372121_75011044) has provided some key pointers in a comment, here is how the complete LDAP Filter would look like:

```bash
$date  = [datetime]::Now.ToFileTimeUtc()
$group = (Get-ADGroup Employees).DistinguishedName

$filter = -join @(
    "(&"                                                   # AND (all conditions must be met)
        "(!userAccountControl:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=2)"  # Enabled Object
        "(mail=*@domain.com)"                              # mail ends with `@domain.com`
        "(memberOf=$group)"                                # object is a member of `$group`
        "(|"                                               # OR (one of the conditions must be met)
            "(accountExpires>=$date)"                      # account expiration is greater than Now (UTC)
            "(accountExpires=0)"                           # account never expires
            "(accountExpires=9223372036854775807)"         # account never expires
        ")"                                                # closing OR clause
    ")"                                                    # closing AND clause
)

Get-ADUser -LDAPFilter $filter -Properties EmailAddress, AccountExpirationDate |
    Select-Object GivenName, Surname, EmailAddress, AccountExpirationDate |
    Export-Csv -Path "export.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: @ScottDyreson could you copy paste the content of `$filter` here?

Comment: I combined the filter into one row and then it works.  It looks like this. 
$filter = "(&(!userAccountControl:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=2) (mail=*@domain.com)(memberOf=$group)(|(accountExpires>=$date)(accountExpires=0)(accountExpires=9223372036854775807)))"  
Thanks for your help.

Comment: @ScottDyreson seems like `$group` and `$date` didnt expand > `(memberOf=$group)` ? that shouldnt be possible. Are you sure it's using double quotes instead of single quotes?

Comment: @ScottDyreson I clearly had typos on the filter syntax, that was my bad. The one from now should work